Names of cities given by Onkelos east of Jordan
There seem to be several changes that Targum Onkelos makes when giving names of the 9 cities east of Jordan.

The city Atarot. Bamidbar 32:3: מכללתא; Bamidbar 32:35: עטרות

The city Dibon. Bamidbar 32:3: מלבשתא; Bamidbar 32:34: דיבון

The city Jazer. Bamidbar 32:3: כומרין; Bamidbar 32:35: יעזר.

The city Nimra. Bamidbar 32:3: בית נימרין; Bamidbar 32:36 בית נימרה

The city of Heshbon. Bamidbar 32:3: בית חשבנא; Bamidbar 32:37 חשבון

The city Elealeh. Bamidbar 32:3: בעלי דבבא; Bamidbar 32:37 אלעלא

The city Sibmah / S'bam. Bamidbar 32:3 סימא (סיעת); Bamidbar 32:38: שבמה

The city Nevo. Bamidbar 32:3: בית קבורתא דמושה; Bamidbar 32:38: נבו

The city Beon. Bamidbar 32:3: בען; Bamidbar 32:38: בעל מעון.


In most cases earlier name in the Torah matches the later one, however Onkelos does not always copy names. Why?

https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=8b

@DoubleAA gemara Brachos 8b speaks of later pesukim as the question states. However, the earlier names do not seem like a translation. Are they names at the time of the Targum?

The first names are identifications of the ancient sites by the author of the targum (similar to, for example, the gemara's identification of Sukkot with Dir Ala [דיר עלא, today Deir Alla in Jordan]). Why the difference between the verse is an interesting question.

According to Rabbi Refael Binyamin Posen in his book Parshegen (פרשגן) on Onkelos (Bamidbar, pp. 665-667 and nn.), the best manuscripts of Onkelos don't have the Aramaic of verse 3. It seems that this Aramaic list of names originated in one manuscript tradition of Targum Yerushalmi, and at one point some scribes mixed in this translation into some manuscript copies of Onkelos, and from there it made its way to the Onkelos of the editio princeps (first printed edition) of Mikraot Gedolot. In other words, Onkelos was consistent, but later scribes botched up some branches of the textual tradition and unfortunately these were used for Mikraot Gedolot, which is how this version of Onkelos was popularized and why this translation is thought to be original. It should also be noted that there are several variants to this list in other manuscripts of Targum Yerushalmi, including some significant changes.1
Per Rabbi Posen, I'll also correct my comment on the question: It's not entirely certain that these Aramaic names are Roman-era identifications of these Tanachic sites, because some of the names are literal translations of the Hebrew. For example, another version of the Targum Yerushalmi translates יעזר as סיען (Si'an); in Hebrew the word סיוע means עזרה (Ezra: help, assist). Nevo actually appears as-is in later sources, so the name בית קבורתא דמושה (the burial of Moshe) simply comes to explain the significance of the site and was likely not the actual name of the Roman period town at the site. Rabbi Yehoshua Falk (or Valk) in his commentary Beit Yisrael (AKA Perisha and Derisha) on the Tur, Hilchot Shabbat, § 285 also explained the name מכללתא as a literal translation of עטרות, because עטרה (Atarah) means crown, and מכללתא in his opinion comes from כליל (Kelil), which also means crown. On the other hand, בית נימרה/נימרין is known from contemporary sources (including being Yerushalmi Shevi'it 9:2's proposed identification of Nimrah). And כומרין in particular caught my eye because of its phonetic similarity to Qumran, and it has been suggested in the past that Qumran is derived from כומריא (Kumria, which means "priests" in Syriac (also related to כומר [komer] in Hebrew). While the general area of Ya'azer is far from Qumran, in light of the phonetic and possible etymological similarity, it's possible that there is a preservation of a real site name here.

1 For a full list of variants, see Alexander Sperber, כתבי הקדש בארמית, vol. 1, p. 279, verse 32. Can be found on Otzar Hachochmah.

Parshegen is great; +1

Ramban to Bamidbar 32:38 explains that the cities changed their names twice after they got the names from the Moabites who settled them before (1).  After the Amorites' conquest, the new rulers named them after their idols. When bnei Reuven and Bnei Gad aquired the cities from Amorites they returned the original Moabite names (because they wanted to shame the Amorites and because they did not want to call the names of their idols). Chizkuni (citing Bechor Shor), Rashi and R. Saadia Gaon offer other reasons, but the Ramban's seems to be the most compelling.

(1) The Torah states that Moabites took over the territory of giant Refaim (Eimim) Devarim 2:10-11. Most likely, it happened because Refaim were smitten by the army of 4 kings Bereshis 14:5. It is not clear if Moabites established the cities or they resettled them.
